# Can Azure dashboard dynamically add widgets?

Tags: azure, dashboard

Azure has a dashboard where we can add widgets for our pipelines and releases

Is it possible to configure this dashboard to dynamically add a new widget, when we add a new build- or release-pipeline?

More specifically we would like the dashboard to show release pipeline widgets for all releases defined in a specific folder

Or do we have to manually add a new widget, when we add a new release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [custom widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget?view=azure-devops).
You can find the release REST API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

Good luck with that!